# Can we get the source code location of the caller in a procedural macro attribute?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

I have requirement to get the source location of the caller of every method. I am trying to create a `proc_macro_attribute` to capture the location and print it.

```rust
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn get_location(attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // Get and print file!(), line!() of source
    // Should print line no. 11
    item
}
```

```rust
#[get_location]
fn add(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 {
    x + y
}

fn main() {
    add(1, 5); // Line No. 11
}
```

Comment: See also [How can I access a function's calling location each time it's called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60714284/7246614)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ready to use solutions are available (see @timotree 's comment). If you want to do this yourself, have more flexibility or learn, you can write a procedural macro that will parse a backtrace (obtained from inside the function that is called) and print the information that you need. Here is a procedural macro inside a `lib.rs`:

```
extern crate proc_macro;
use proc_macro::{TokenStream, TokenTree};

#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn get_location(_attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {

    // prefix code to be added to the function's body
    let mut prefix: TokenStream = "
        // find earliest symbol in source file using backtrace
        let ps = Backtrace::new().frames().iter()
            .flat_map(BacktraceFrame::symbols)
            .skip_while(|s| s.filename()
                .map(|p|!p.ends_with(file!())).unwrap_or(true))
            .nth(1 as usize).unwrap();

        println!(\"Called from {:?} at line {:?}\",
            ps.filename().unwrap(), ps.lineno().unwrap());
    ".parse().unwrap(); // parse string into TokenStream

    item.into_iter().map(|tt| { // edit input TokenStream
        match tt { 
            TokenTree::Group(ref g) // match the function's body
                if g.delimiter() == proc_macro::Delimiter::Brace => { 

                    prefix.extend(g.stream()); // add parsed string

                    TokenTree::Group(proc_macro::Group::new(
                        proc_macro::Delimiter::Brace, prefix.clone()))
            },
            other => other, // else just forward TokenTree
        }
    }).collect()
}
```

The backtrace is parsed to find the earliest symbol inside the source file (retrieved using `file!()`, another macro). The code we need to add to the function is defined in a string, that is then parsed as a `TokenStream` and added at the beginning of the function's body. We could have added this logic at the end, but then returning a value without a semicolon wouldn't work anymore. You can then use the procedural macro in your `main.rs` as follow:

```
extern crate backtrace;
use backtrace::{Backtrace, BacktraceFrame};
use mylib::get_location;

#[get_location]
fn add(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 { x + y }

fn main() { 
    add(1, 41);
    add(41, 1);
}
```

The output is:

```
> Called from "src/main.rs" at line 10
> Called from "src/main.rs" at line 11
```

Don't forget to specify that your `lib` crate is providing procedural macros by adding these two lines to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[lib]
proc-macro = true
```

Comment: Thanks Victor. I should have asked different question actually. I didn't find a way to modify function in tokenstream, which I got form your example. 

Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure. Do you need more explanations as to how the function is modified ? You can also ask another question if needed

Comment: Will do. I got enough information from your example. Thanks again Victor

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

Here is a procedural macro that uses [`syn`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0/syn/) and [`quote`](https://docs.rs/quote/1.0/quote/) to do what you've described:

```rust
// print_caller_location/src/lib.rs

use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
use syn::spanned::Spanned;

// Create a procedural attribute macro
//
// Notably, this must be placed alone in its own crate
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn print_caller_location(_attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // Parse the passed item as a function
    let func = syn::parse_macro_input!(item as syn::ItemFn);

    // Break the function down into its parts
    let syn::ItemFn {
        attrs,
        vis,
        sig,
        block,
    } = func;

    // Ensure that it isn't an `async fn`
    if let Some(async_token) = sig.asyncness {
        // Error out if so
        let error = syn::Error::new(
            async_token.span(),
            "async functions do not support caller tracking functionality
    help: consider returning `impl Future` instead",
        );

        return TokenStream::from(error.to_compile_error());
    }

    // Wrap body in a closure only if function doesn't already have #[track_caller]
    let block = if attrs.iter().any(|attr| attr.path.is_ident("track_caller")) {
        quote! { #block }
    } else {
        quote! {
            (move || #block)()
        }
    };

    // Extract function name for prettier output
    let name = format!("{}", sig.ident);

    // Generate the output, adding `#[track_caller]` as well as a `println!`
    let output = quote! {
        #[track_caller]
        #(#attrs)*
        #vis #sig {
            println!(
                "entering `fn {}`: called from `{}`",
                #name,
                ::core::panic::Location::caller()
            );
            #block
        }
    };

    // Convert the output from a `proc_macro2::TokenStream` to a `proc_macro::TokenStream`
    TokenStream::from(output)
}
```

Make sure to put it in its on crate and add these lines to its `Cargo.toml`:

```toml
# print_caller_location/Cargo.toml

[lib]
proc-macro = true

[dependencies]
syn = {version = "1.0.16", features = ["full"]}
quote = "1.0.3"
proc-macro2 = "1.0.9"
```

### In-depth explanation

A macro can only expand to code that's possible to write by hand to begin with. Knowing this, I see two questions here:

1. How can I write a function that tracks the location of its caller?

   - See [How can I access a function's calling location each time it's called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60714284/72466140)

     > Short answer: to obtain the location in which your function gets called, mark it with `#[track_caller]` and use [`std::panic::Location::caller`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/struct.Location.html#method.caller) in its body.
2. How can I write a procedural macro that creates such functions?

### Initial attempt

We want a procedural macro that

- takes a function,
- marks it `#[track_caller]`,
- and adds a line that prints [`Location::caller`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/struct.Location.html#method.caller).

For example, it would transform a function like this:

```rust
fn foo() {
    // body of foo
}
```

into

```rust
#[track_caller]
fn foo() {
    println!("{}", std::panic::Location::caller());
    // body of foo
}
```

Below, I present a procedural macro that executes that transformation exactly — although, as you'll see in later versions, you probably want something different. To try this code, like before in the TL;DR section, put it into its own crate and add its dependencies to the `Cargo.toml`.

```rust
// print_caller_location/src/lib.rs

use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;

// Create a procedural attribute macro
//
// Notably, this must be placed alone in its own crate
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn print_caller_location(_attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // Parse the passed item as a function
    let func = syn::parse_macro_input!(item as syn::ItemFn);

    // Break the function down into its parts
    let syn::ItemFn {
        attrs,
        vis,
        sig,
        block,
    } = func;

    // Extract function name for prettier output
    let name = format!("{}", sig.ident);

    // Generate the output, adding `#[track_caller]` as well as a `println!`
    let output = quote! {
        #[track_caller]
        #(#attrs)*
        #vis #sig {
            println!(
                "entering `fn {}`: called from `{}`",
                #name,
                ::core::panic::Location::caller()
            );
            #block
        }
    };

    // Convert the output from a `proc_macro2::TokenStream` to a `proc_macro::TokenStream`
    TokenStream::from(output)
}
```

Example usage:

```rust
// example1/src/main.rs

#![feature(track_caller)]

#[print_caller_location::print_caller_location]
fn add(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 {
    x + y
}

fn main() {
    add(1, 5); // entering `fn add`: called from `example1/src/main.rs:11:5`
    add(1, 5); // entering `fn add`: called from `example1/src/main.rs:12:5`
}
```

Unfortunately, we won't be able to get away with that simple version. There are at least two problems with that version:

- How it composes with `async fn`s:

  - Instead of printing the caller location, it prints the location in which our macro (`#[print_caller_location]`) is invoked. For example:

  ```
  // example2/src/main.rs

  #![feature(track_caller)]

  #[print_caller_location::print_caller_location]
  async fn foo() {}

  fn main() {
      let future = foo();
      // ^ oops! prints nothing
      futures::executor::block_on(future);
      // ^ oops! prints "entering `fn foo`: called from `example2/src/main.rs:5:1`"
      let future = foo();
      // ^ oops! prints nothing
      futures::executor::block_on(future);
      // ^ oops! prints "entering `fn foo`: called from `example2/src/main.rs:5:1`"
  }
  ```
- How it works with other invocations of itself, or generally, of `#[track_caller]`:

  - Nested functions with `#[print_caller_location]` will print the location of the root caller, rather than the direct caller of a given function. For example:

  ```
  // example3/src/main.rs

  #![feature(track_caller)]

  #[print_caller_location::print_caller_location]
  fn add(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 {
      x + y
  }

  #[print_caller_location::print_caller_location]
  fn add_outer(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 {
      add(x, y)
      // ^ we would expect "entering `fn add`: called from `example3/src/main.rs:12:5`"
  }

  fn main() {
      add(1, 5);
      // ^ "entering `fn add`: called from `example3/src/main.rs:17:5`"
      add(1, 5);
      // ^ "entering `fn add`: called from `example3/src/main.rs:19:5`"
      add_outer(1, 5);
      // ^ "entering `fn add_outer`: called from `example3/src/main.rs:21:5`"
      // ^ oops! "entering `fn add`: called from `example3/src/main.rs:21:5`"
      //
      // In reality, `add` was called on line 12, from within the body of `add_outer`
      add_outer(1, 5);
      // ^ "entering `fn add_outer`: called from `example3/src/main.rs:26:5`"
      // oops! ^ entering `fn add`: called from `example3/src/main.rs:26:5`
      //
      // In reality, `add` was called on line 12, from within the body of `add_outer`
  }
  ```

### Addressing `async fn`s

It is possible to work around the problem with `async fn`s using `-> impl Future`, for example, if we wanted our `async fn` counter-example to work correctly, we could instead write:

```rust
// example4/src/main.rs

#![feature(track_caller)]

use std::future::Future;

#[print_caller_location::print_caller_location]
fn foo() -> impl Future<Output = ()> {
    async move {
        // body of foo
    }
}

fn main() {
    let future = foo();
    // ^ prints "entering `fn foo`: called from `example4/src/main.rs:15:18`"
    futures::executor::block_on(future);
    // ^ prints nothing
    let future = foo();
    // ^ prints "entering `fn foo`: called from `example4/src/main.rs:19:18`"
    futures::executor::block_on(future);
    // ^ prints nothing
}
```

We could add a special case that applies this transformation to our macro. However, that transformation changes the public API of the function from `async fn foo()` to `fn foo() -> impl Future<Output = ()>` in addition to affecting the auto traits that the returned future can have.

Therefore I recommend that we allow users to use that workaround if they desire, and simply emit an error if our macro is used on an `async fn`. We can do this by adding these lines to our macro code:

```rust
// Ensure that it isn't an `async fn`
if let Some(async_token) = sig.asyncness {
    // Error out if so
    let error = syn::Error::new(
        async_token.span(),
        "async functions do not support caller tracking functionality
    help: consider returning `impl Future` instead",
    );

    return TokenStream::from(error.to_compile_error());
}
```

### Fixing nested behavior of `#[print_caller_location]` functions

The problematic behaviour minimizes down to this fact: When a `#[track_caller]` function, `foo`, directly calls into another `#[track_caller]` function, `bar`, `Location::caller` will give both of them access to `foo`'s caller. In other words, `Location::caller` gives access to the root caller in the case of nested `#[track_caller]` functions:

```rust
#![feature(track_caller)]

fn main() {
    foo(); // prints `src/main.rs:4:5` instead of the line number in `foo`
}

#[track_caller]
fn foo() {
   bar();
}

#[track_caller]
fn bar() {
    println!("{}", std::panic::Location::caller());
}
```

[*playground link*](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d1a77c74947a436aa211b99487824004)

To remedy this, we need to break the chain of `#[track_caller]` calls. We can break the chain by hiding the nested call to `bar` within a closure:

```rust
#![feature(track_caller)]

fn main() {
    foo();
}

#[track_caller]
fn foo() {
    (move || {
        bar(); // prints `src/main.rs:10:9`
    })()
}

#[track_caller]
fn bar() {
    println!("{}", std::panic::Location::caller());
}
```

[*playground link*](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9bddd7cfd7f69a2a6079ff6b7dba32e3)

Now that we know how to break the chain of `#[track_caller]` functions, we can address this problem. We just need to make sure that if the user actually marks their function with `#[track_caller]` on purpose, we refrain from inserting the closure and breaking the chain.

We can add these lines to our solution:

```rust
// Wrap body in a closure only if function doesn't already have #[track_caller]
let block = if attrs.iter().any(|attr| attr.path.is_ident("track_caller")) {
    quote! { #block }
} else {
    quote! {
        (move || #block)()
    }
};
```

### Final solution

After those two changes, we've ended up with this code:

```rust
// print_caller_location/src/lib.rs

use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
use syn::spanned::Spanned;

// Create a procedural attribute macro
//
// Notably, this must be placed alone in its own crate
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn print_caller_location(_attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // Parse the passed item as a function
    let func = syn::parse_macro_input!(item as syn::ItemFn);

    // Break the function down into its parts
    let syn::ItemFn {
        attrs,
        vis,
        sig,
        block,
    } = func;

    // Ensure that it isn't an `async fn`
    if let Some(async_token) = sig.asyncness {
        // Error out if so
        let error = syn::Error::new(
            async_token.span(),
            "async functions do not support caller tracking functionality
    help: consider returning `impl Future` instead",
        );

        return TokenStream::from(error.to_compile_error());
    }

    // Wrap body in a closure only if function doesn't already have #[track_caller]
    let block = if attrs.iter().any(|attr| attr.path.is_ident("track_caller")) {
        quote! { #block }
    } else {
        quote! {
            (move || #block)()
        }
    };

    // Extract function name for prettier output
    let name = format!("{}", sig.ident);

    // Generate the output, adding `#[track_caller]` as well as a `println!`
    let output = quote! {
        #[track_caller]
        #(#attrs)*
        #vis #sig {
            println!(
                "entering `fn {}`: called from `{}`",
                #name,
                ::core::panic::Location::caller()
            );
            #block
        }
    };

    // Convert the output from a `proc_macro2::TokenStream` to a `proc_macro::TokenStream`
    TokenStream::from(output)
}
```

Comment: This is superb. Thanks.