# How can I access a function's calling location each time it's called?

Tags: debugging, rust

I would like to write a function that accesses the file and line number of the location in which it gets called.

It would look like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    prints_calling_location(); // would print `called from line: 2`
    prints_calling_location(); // would print `called from line: 3`
}

fn prints_calling_location() {
    let caller_line_number = /* ??? */;
    println!("called from line: {}", caller_line_number);
}
```

Comment: You can manually write a procedural macro to accomplish like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60692131/can-we-get-location-of-source-caller-in-proc-macro-attribute-in-rust/60731879#60731879). It works by parsing a backtrace at runtime

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[RFC 2091: Implicit caller location](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2091) adds the `track_caller` feature which enables a function to access the location of its caller.

Short answer: to obtain the location in which your function gets called, mark it with `#[track_caller]` and use [`std::panic::Location::caller`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/struct.Location.html#method.caller) in its body.

Following from that answer, your example would look like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    prints_calling_location(); // would print `called from line: 2`
    prints_calling_location(); // would print `called from line: 3`
}

#[track_caller]
fn prints_calling_location() {
    let caller_location = std::panic::Location::caller();
    let caller_line_number = caller_location.line();
    println!("called from line: {}", caller_line_number);
}
```

[*playground link*](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0261d65d00cc11ae23e2b9f78e3271f8)

More specifically, the function [`std::panic::Location::caller`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/struct.Location.html#method.caller) has two behaviors:

- Within a function marked `#[track_caller]`, it returns a `&'static Location<'static>` which you can use to find out the file, line number, and column number in which your function gets called.
- Within a function that doesn't have `#[track_caller]`, it has the error-prone behavior of returning the actual location where you've invoked it, not where your function gets called, for example:

  ```rust
  fn main() {
      oops();
      // ^ prints `line: 8` instead of the expected `line: 2`
  }

  // note: missing #[track_caller] here
  fn oops() {
      println!("line: {}", std::panic::Location::caller().line());
  }
  ```

  [*playground link*](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8eb9b7272ea4b9c48448c533f16d8bb1)

Comment: At the current version, it got stabilized and can be used without `#![feature(...)]`

Comment: It might have been stabilized some time ago, but i only found the existence of `#[track_caller]` right now

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using the "Implicit caller location" (which may not be available/suitable to you for whatever reason) is to do things the C way. 
I.e. hide your function behind a macro.

```
macro_rules! prints_calling_location {
    () => { 
        let caller_line_number = line!();
        println!("called from line: {}", caller_line_number);
    };
}

fn main() {
    prints_calling_location!(); // prints `called from line: 10`
    prints_calling_location!(); // prints `called from line: 11`
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d652b3ff4d4d0bc31abea839abe42be9)