# Why does std::panic::Location::caller not return an Option?

Tags: rust

The definition of [`Location::caller`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/struct.Location.html#method.caller) states:

> ```rust
> pub fn caller() -> &'static Location<'static>`
> ```
>
> This is a nightly-only experimental API. (`track_caller` [#47809](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/47809))
>
> Returns the source location of the caller of this function. 
>   If that function's caller is annotated then its call location 
>   will be returned, and so on up the stack to the first call within a 
>   non-tracked function body.

That sounds to me like it should return `&'static Option<Location<'static>>`.
Anything else seems to make walking the call stack much harder than it could be.

Is there a good reason for this decision?

Comment: You mention walking the call stack, but as far as I know that's not the usecase of this API. Given the usage of finding the specific caller of a given callsite of `Location::caller()`, what is the case where `None` would be the response value?

Comment: Ah, you're right I was thinking the function was `caller(&self) -> Location` and that you'd get the root Location from the `PanicInfo::location`, so that you could walk the callstack via `while(location = location.caller()) { ... }`. But it doesn't give you that, just one point somewhere up the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible for a running function to not have a caller, so there's no time where `None` would be a possible return value.

You may be confused by the seemingly-poorly-worded clause:

> If that function's caller is annotated [sic] then its call location will be returned

That probably should be worded as "annotated with `#[track_caller]`". What that means is that when the attribute is present, it's as if the function didn't exist and was textually inlined where it was called from.

See also:

- [Tracking issue for RFC 2091: Implicit caller location](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/47809)
- [RFC: Implicit caller location #2091](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2091)
- [How can I access a function's calling location each time it's called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60714284/155423)

Comment: I think it was just misread by me - I had thought it meant it would only work if the function was annotated with `track_caller`. I also missed that it did not have an `&self` argument - which made me think it supported chaining like `here.caller().caller()` to take two steps up the call chain.