# Is there a way to get the file and the module path of where a procedural macro is attached at compile-time?

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I'm looking for the equivalent of `file!()` & `module_path!()` in a procedural macro context.

For example, the following doesn't work:

`file.rs`:

```rust
#[some_attribute]
const A: bool = true;
```

`macro.rs`:

```rust
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn some_attribute(attr: TokenStream, input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    println!("{}", file!());

    input
}
```

This prints `macro.rs` which makes sense, but what I want is `file.rs`. Is there a way to achieve this? Is there also a similar way for `module_path!()`?

A requirement of this is that has to happen at compile-time.

I'm trying to create a file in the `OUT_DIR` containing constant values where the attribute is added with the module and the file that they are in.

Comment: There's a nightly API to [get the source file for a `Span`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.Span.html#method.source_file) (which you can get from a `TokenTree` using the `span()` method), but at a glance I didn't find a way to access the module path, nor did I find a way that works on stable.

Comment: This is currently unstable as per @SvenMarnach's comment, however if you could give us some details about your use case, we might help with alternatives.

Comment: My use case is a bit complicated, but basically what I'm trying to achieve is to create a file in `OUT_DIR` during compile-time of all the `const` values where the attribute is added with the module and the file that they are in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem and found out that Rust added a new experimential API to Rust macros ([#54725](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54725)) which allows exactly what you want:

```rs
#![feature(proc_macro_span)]

#[proc_macro]
pub(crate) fn do_something(item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let span = Span::call_site();
    let source = span.source_file();
    format!("println!(r#\"Path: {}\"#)", source.path().to_str().unwrap())
        .parse()
        .unwrap()
}
```

```rs
use my_macro_crate::*;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    do_something!();
}
```

Will output:

```
Hello, world!
Path: src\main.rs
```

### Important

Apart from this API being experimential, the path might not be a real OS path. This can be the case if the `Span` was generated by a macro. Visit the documentation [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.SourceFile.html).

Comment: I use this in a macro of mine (I want the path to the source file where the macro is used), and I would really like to get off nightly and back on to stable - and this is my only need for nightly in a large project. :-( I'm asking for help on Discord #macros channel also, but if anyone here knows that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes. This does not work on stable, even enabling the source_file() method via semver flags, so you (we :-( ) are stuck on nightly to get the source file name. Discord users help and said I need this done first: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3200 FYI

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `println!("{}", file!());` is executed at *compile time* and not at runtime. Similar to an answer that was recently given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60692131/can-we-get-the-source-code-location-of-the-caller-in-a-procedural-macro-attribut/), you can edit the original function and insert your code at the beginning of it, which will be executed at *runtime* this time. You can still use the procedural macros `file!()` and `module_path!()`. Here is a `macro.rs` with this approach:

```
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn some_attribute(_attr: TokenStream, input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {

    // prefix to be added to the function's body
    let mut prefix: TokenStream = "
        println!(\"Called from {:?} inside module path {:?}\",
            file!(), module_path!());
    ".parse().unwrap();

    // edit TokenStream
    input.into_iter().map(|tt| { 
        match tt { 
            TokenTree::Group(ref g) // match function body
                if g.delimiter() == proc_macro::Delimiter::Brace => { 

                    // add logic before function body
                    prefix.extend(g.stream()); 

                    // return new function body as TokenTree
                    TokenTree::Group(proc_macro::Group::new(
                        proc_macro::Delimiter::Brace, prefix.clone()))
            },
            other => other, // else just forward
        }
    }).collect()
}
```

You can use it like this in your `main.rs`:

```
use mylib::some_attribute;

#[some_attribute]
fn yo() -> () { println!("yo"); }

fn main() { yo(); }
```

Note that the code is added *before* what's inside of the function's body. We could have inserted it at the end, but this would break the possibility of returning a value without a semicolon.

EDIT: Later realized that the OP wants it to run at *compile time*.

Comment: I was assuming the OP tried to access the information at compile time rather than at runtime, but reading the question again, this answer probably is what they want.

Comment: @SvenMarnach is right, I do want the information at compile time.

Comment: My bad ! I will leave my answer nevertheless, as I think it contributed to the understanding of the question